# How to select only direct children with angular platform-browser By.css() function?

Tags: angular, angular-test, queryselector

I have this HTML structure:

```html
<tabset data-test-id="main-tabset">
  <tab data-test-id="general">
    <tabset data-test-id="lang-tabset">
      <tab data-test-id="lang-1">
        ...
      </tab>
      <tab data-test-id="lang-2">
        ...
      </tab>
  </tab>
  <tab data-test-id="settings">
    ...
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

I want to select only direct`tab` children of `[data-test-id="main-tabset"]`.

I tried this:

```js
debugElement.queryAll(By.css(`[data-test-id="main-tabset"] > tab`))
```

But this isn't works for me. The result contains all children `tab` elements.

How can I query only direct children?

Comment: Selector looks fine. Should return only "top level" tab elements.

Comment: Yes, but still... it returns with all children tab elements... maybe it's a bug or is there any trick to implement this solution?